# How to access a control inside of GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, learning as I go and I have the following question:

I have a GridView defined inside UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate> 
   <div id="divIsoSelect" style="width:700px; height:60px; background-color:white">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">Search ISO by</legend>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlISOSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlISOSearch_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="">Select...</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ISO Number" >ISO Number</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Name">Name</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Region" >Region</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Division">Division</asp:ListItem>                
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
           <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchEntry" runat="server" Visible="false" style="width:500px; border:gainsboro; border-width: thick;">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="width:120px"><asp:Label ID="lblEntry" runnat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>

                <td valign="top"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                <td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btnFind_Click"/></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>               
</fieldset>
</div>
        <div>    
        <p> <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" style="position:absolute; left: 221px; top: 110px;"></asp:Label></p>
        </div>
        <div>

            <asp:GridView ID="grvIsoSearchResults" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="10"
                AllowPaging = "true" Visible="true"  BorderColor="Red" GridLines="Both"
                OnPageIndexChanged="grvIsoSearchResults_PageIndexChanged" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="grvIsoSearchResults_PageIndexChanging" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="grvIsoSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanging="grvIsoSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanging">
                <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next" PageButtonCount="100" />
                <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ISONUM">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvIsoNum" Text = '<%# Eval("ISONUM")%>' runat="server" Width="70px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OFFICE NAME">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvIsoOfficeName" Text = '<%# Eval("ISOOFFICENAME")%>' runat="server" Width="200px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REGION">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvRegion" Text = '<%# Eval("REGION")%>' runat="server" Width="50px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DIVISION">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtgvDivision" Text = '<%# Eval("CLIENT_ID")%>' runat="server" Width="50px" style="text-align:center" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMAIL ADDRESS">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtgvEmailAddress" Text = '<%# Eval("EMAIL")%>' runat="server" Width="300px" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateEmail" Text = "Update" runat="server" Width="70px" OnClientClick="ValidateEmail()"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>                    
        </div>           

 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
  <ProgressTemplate>
           Please Wait.....
  </ProgressTemplate>
  </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Now I want to validate my email field:

```
   function ValidateEmail()
   {
       var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtgvEmailAddress.ClientID%>').value;
   }
```

But I cannot access my email field inside of gridview. What should I do to fix it?

Thank yo

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to validate whether the email address is valid then you can do this with a asp:RegularExpression control.  Include this right under your textbox control.  Get rid of the OnClientClick on your button.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="txtgvEmailAddress" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I already tried that one. What happened was, I got Error messages on each row where I have a valid email address. Also, my DropDown section stopped working as soon as email is checked. In DropDown section, I have a button that is clicked and should search for the data. And nothing happens after validation executed

Answer (score 0):

You must store the rowindex in a HTML hiddenfeild which must have clientidmode property static....

```
function ValidateEmail()
   {
    var rowindex=document.getElementById('hiddenfeild').value;
    if(document.getElementById('grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_' + rowindex.toString() + '').value=="")
    {
      //write your code here
    }
}
```